# Can I execute GRANT statement in a stored procedure using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to get a list of tables and then grant the permissions to a specific user for accessing these tables.

When I write a stored procedure for this ^, I get a strange error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1"

But if I replace the GRANT query with select query it executes ok. I am assuming that the GRANT statements are not allowed in the stored procedures. Is that correct.

p.s. I am executing the grant statement using prepare statements.

Comment: This question completely lacks code

Comment: Stored procedures and prepared statements allows the `GRANT` statement. As mentioned @Drew, post your code to help better.

Comment: Can you show us the result of prepared statement? or show your SQL code?