# Calling GRANT within a stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-grant

I try to grant access within a stored procedure and I have an error.

my stored procedure is :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyShema.up_MyStoredProcedureName
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS
BEGIN

  GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT :: MyBD.MyShema.vw_MyViewToGiveAccess TO sqlUserGroup
  GO
END
```

But when I try to create it, it gives my this error :

```
Msg 102, Niveau 15, État 1, Procédure up_MyStoredProcedureName, Ligne 41 Incorrect syntax near 'sqlUserGroup'.
Msg 102, Niveau 15, État 1, Ligne 44 Incorrect syntax near 'END'.
```

But when I execute this GRANT command alone (not in a stored procedure creation), it works. So my userGroup and my tables name are ok.

How do we do that?

I only found one post in stack overflow about a similar question (call grant in a stored procedure) but it is not answered yet. It tells that we can to it but still have not yet example about it.
[Can I execute GRANT statement in a stored procedure using MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348738/can-i-execute-grant-statement-in-a-stored-procedure-using-mysql)

Thanks in advance for your help

note : I'm currently working with a sql server of version 2008

Answer (score 1):

Add brackets [sqlUserGroup] and add domain if exists.

Remove GO.